# unable to connect to JSON service in android application of Titanium studio

Tags: android, titanium

i am trying to do login application which takes id and password..when i click on logi button then it will connect to our local server by JSON..with the specified URL..the code is..

```
   var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
   loginReq.onload = function() 
   { 
     var json = this.responseText; alert(json); 
        var response = JSON.parse(json); 
        if (response.data.status == "success") 
         { alert("Welcome "); 
           } 
          else 
          { alert(response.data.status); 
        } 
             };

           loginReq.onerror = function(event)
              {
             alert(event.toSource()); 
             //alert("Network error"); 
                 };

         loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e) 
         { if (username.value != '' && password.value != '') 
         {
          var url = 'our local url                               action=login&amp;id='+username.value+'&amp;pwd='+password.value;
         loginReq.open(&quot;POST&quot;,url);
        loginReq.send();
          }
          else
           {
            alert(&quot;Username/Password are required&quot;);
           }
            });
```

Here it is not connecting our URl..so it is entering into loginReq.onerror function...instead of loginReq.onload function..why it is throwing run time error.. The same code working fine with Iphone..
The Run Time Error is..
TypeError:Cannot call property toSource in object{'source':[Ti.Network.HttpClient],specified url} is not a function,it is a object.

This is wat the error..please let me Know...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the toSource() function does not exist in android, as it is an object. Try debugging and see what the object event contains.

You could do that by adding a line above the alert line, and adding a debug line to it.

Look in debug mode and see all variables

Answer (score 0):

"toSource()" is not a documented function for either platform, and I also do not see it in the source for Titanium Mobile. If you aren't getting the error on iOS, I'm guessing it is because the error handler isn't getting called. Perhaps your emulator or device does not have internet access, whereas your iOS simulator or device does?

Regardless, error handling in the HTTPClient normally looks something like this:

```
loginReq.onerror = function(e)
{
    Ti.API.info("ERROR " + e.error);
    alert(e.error);
};
```